# How to make diamond shape using graphiti?

Tags: raphael, draw2d, graphiti-js

Can you please provide me how to make diamond shape in graphiti , i have tried it using RestoreBridge example but that example is SVG import so please provide me some idea or code for making diamond like shapes ( resizable and draggable diamond ).

Thanks in advance:)

Comment: I have done with diamond shape as well, need to edit the triangle.js and little coordinate management and its done...Thanks guys:)

Comment: Common courtesy on this site is to "accept" the answer that you've found most useful and up-vote others that have helped you. Please give some credit to the people who are helping you - they'd appreciate it. Don't forget, by doing this, other people who have the same issue can easily find the best solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Diamond" shape is part of graphiti 0.9.34

inspect the package "graphiti.shape.basic.*"